# Jenkins Pipeline : Passing a parameter from one job to another

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins v2.73.2 and wanted to pass a String parameter from one job (TEST_JOB) to another job (BUILD_JOB) using pipeline script feature. I understand same is done as below without pipeline by installing “Parameterized Trigger Plugin” , Job 1(upstream job) > Post-Build Actions > Select ”Trigger parameterized build on other projects”
In the Downstream Job: To access this parameter we use $(Parameter name).

I want the same to be done with Pipeline . By googing i found few eaxmples and based on it i have created this way but getting below error message

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class jenkins.plugins.git.GitStep.setBranch() expects class java.lang.String but received class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:394)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.injectSetters(DescribableModel.java:338)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:261)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:201)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:205)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:150)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1435.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {url=ssh://git@source.pmi.corp:7999/vitalpoint/vitalpoint-5.git, credentialsId=8749a398-8b66-490e-bbdc-c582d1a4156e, branch=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@5afc818} for GitStep(url: String, branch?: String, changelog?: boolean, credentialsId?: String, poll?: boolean)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:264)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.newInstance(StepDescriptor.java:201)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:205)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:150)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1435.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:6)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1339.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1372.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

First Job : (TEST_JOB)  -

```groovy
node('Jenkins_1') {
    stage ('Build') {
        build job: 'BUILD_JOB', parameters: [$class: 'StringParameterValue',name: 'BRANCH_BUILD', value: "${params.BRANCH}")]
        }
    }
```

NOTE : Here, I want to pass params.BRANCH value to the second job (BUILD_JOB)

Second Job : BUILD_JOB -

```groovy
node('Jenkins_1') {

      deleteDir()

      stage 'Checkout'
      git (url: 'ssh://git@source.mmr:7000/demo.git',
      credentialsId: 'XXXXXX',
      branch: '${BRANCH_BUILD}')

      stage 'Build'
      bat 'call "C:\\Program Files \\MSBuild\\12.0\\MSBuild.exe" sample.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release'

      stage 'Archive'
      echo 'Archive'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value you are passing for the parameter? Also please try to change the name of the parameter. I am guessing that it is trying to set some internal variable of Jenkins as the parameter name is matching with it. So please rename the parameter and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In BUILD_JOB, use 
`branch: "${params.BRANCH_BUILD}".`

Note that I made two changes -- I used double quotes and added `params` as prefix to passing parameter.